# How to solve error "Bind variable ? not set"?

Tags: java, spring-boot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an SQL query written in Java that should connect to Snowflake database.

I am using `jdbc` template to connect to Snowflake and this is the string that I am using:

```
url: jdbc:snowflake://xxxxx.eu-central-1.snowflakecomputing.com/?db=DATABASE_NAME&warehouse=TEST_WAREHOUSE&schema=PUBLIC&role=SYSADMIN

user: username
password: password
```

**Here is query:**

```
public void EPI_GAME_REP_QUERY(String id) {
     long userId = Long.parseLong(id);
      String REP_QUERY = "SELECT \n" +
                "                \"ProductName\",\n" +
                "                \"UserID\",\n" +
                "                \"UserName\",\n" +
                "            FROM \"DATABSE4\".\"RAW_DATA\".\"BETA\"\n" +
                "            WHERE \"UserID\" = ? \n" +
                "            UNION ALL\n" +
                "            SELECT \n" +
                "                \"ProductName\",\n" +
                "                \"UserID\",\n" +
                "                \"UserName\",\n" +
                "            FROM \"DATABASE3\".\"RAW_DATA\".\"BETAC\"\n" +
                "            WHERE \"UserID\" = ? \n" +
                "            UNION ALL\n" +
                "            SELECT  \n" +
                "                \"ProductName\",\n" +
                "                \"UserID\",\n" +
                "                \"UserName\",\n" +
                "            FROM \"DATABASE1\".\"RAW_DATA\".\"ACTIVITY\"\n" +
                "            WHERE \"UserID\" = ? \n" +
                "            UNION ALL\n" +
                "            SELECT  \n" +
                "                \"ProductName\",\n" +
                "                \"StartTime\",\n" +
                "                \"UserID\",\n" +
                "                \"UserName\",\n" +
                "            FROM \"DATABASE1\".\"RAW_DATA\".\"HISTORY\"\n" +
                "            WHERE \"UserID\" = ? \n" +
                "            ORDER BY \"StartTime\" ASC;";

        log.info("Executing query...");

        jdbcTemplate.query(REP_QUERY, rs -> {
        },  userId);
    }
```

I am passing `id` as parameter, and because it's `String type` in code and `number type` in database I am parsing it to `int`.

When I run the code, I am getting this error:

```
nested exception is net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL compilation error: error line 33 at position 29
Bind variable ? not set.
```

Comment: There's 4 `?` in your request, so shouldn't you put `userId` 4 times ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You SQL request contains several variable to bind (one for each '?'), and you have to provide a value for each one:

```
jdbcTemplate.query(REP_QUERY, rs -> {},  userId, userId, userId, userId);
```